# How to transfer table from web to my database in Android

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse

I'm making an application where I connect to a website to download a table from my web database in a json string, that I have done, in my app shows as a webArray. I have created a database helper class to create and edit my db inside the application, my problem is that I'm failing on transferring the data from my webArray to my db, here is some pieces of code maybe you could help pointing me on the right direction.

mainActivity:

```
  //this is our download file asynctask
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS2);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {

        try {
        String result = "";
                    try {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite");
                        // httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
                        // convert response to string
                        try {
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            String line = null;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                            webs.close();

                            result = sb.toString();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                            return "ERROR_IN_CODE";
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                        return "ERROR_IN_CODE";
                    }

                    // parse json data
                    try {
                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            webResultCuestionario resultRow3 = new webResultCuestionario();
                            resultRow3._id = json_data.getString("id");
                            resultRow3.pregunta = json_data.getString("Question");
                            resultRow3.respuesta = json_data.getString("Answer");
                            CuestionarioArray.add(resultRow3);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                        return "ERROR_IN_CODE";
                    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // this is the line of code that sends a real error message to the
        // log
        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());
        // this is the line that prints out the location in
        // the code where the error occurred.
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "ERROR_IN_CODE";
    }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         Log.d(LOG_TAG,progress[0]);
         mProgressDialog2.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        //dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS2);
        if(unused != null && unused.equals("ERROR_IN_CODE")){
            errornote2();
        }else{
            tvCuestionario.setText("Cuestionario encontrado");
            addCuestionarioToDb();
        }
    }
}   

public void addCuestionarioToDb(){
for (webResultCuestionario currentItem: CuestionarioArray){
    int cis = Integer.parseInt(currentItem._id);
    db.insertCuestionario(CuestionarioArray.get(cis).pregunta, CuestionarioArray.get(cis).respuesta);
}
}
```

in my CuestionarioHelper Class:

```
public class CuestionarioHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME="cuestionario.db";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION=1;

public CuestionarioHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}   
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Cuestionario (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, pregunta TEXT, respuesta TEXT);");
    }
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

} 

    public void insertCuestionario(String pregunta, String respuesta) {
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("pregunta", pregunta);
    cv.put("respuesta", respuesta);
    getWritableDatabase().insert("Cuestionario", null, cv);
}
```

the log

```
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid  index 100, size is 100
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at    java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at VerCuestionarioEspanol_copy.MainActivity.addCuestionarioToDb(MainActivity.java:580)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at  VerCuestionarioEspanol_copy.MainActivity$DownloadFile3Async.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:46 2)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at  VerCuestionarioEspanol_copy.MainActivity$DownloadFile3Async.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4977)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-23 16:23:02.977: E/AndroidRuntime(6496):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @dor506, well is not adding the items. maybe there will be a different way to add them?

Comment: strange. you're not getting any exception? check the log

Comment: @dor506, Ijust added the log check it out please.

Comment: @zvzej your code is crashing while accessing an array list position 100, for a list with 100 items (valid positions are from 0 to 99). If you double click in the log line "at VerCuestionarioEspanol_copy.MainActivity.addCuestionarioToDb(MainActivity" you will be taken to the line of code generating the issue. Probably is the line "db.insertCuestionario(CuestionarioArray.get(cis).pregunta, CuestionarioArray.get(cis).respuesta);" where cis is geting a value of 100 and the array list only have 99 positions.

Comment: @dor506 the Questionnaire I getting from the webArray is 100 questions and 100 answers so the id for the ending row is 100, and the error line corresponds to db.insertCuestionario(CuestionarioArray.get(cis).pregunta, CuestionarioArray.get(cis).respuesta);

Comment: @Luis  the Questionnaire I getting from the webArray is 100 questions and 100 answers so the id for the ending row is 100, and the error line corresponds to db.insertCuestionario(CuestionarioArray.get(cis).pregunta, CuestionarioArray.get(cis).respuesta);

Comment: @zvzej As I said above, if you have 100 questions (numbered from 1 to 100) when you add them to an array list, the indexs will be numbered from 0 to 99. To get from your question number to the index number you need to subtract 1 from the question number.

Comment: @Luis what happens if there is more that 100 questions?

Comment: @zvzej I'm not sure if I understood your question, but an array in java has always the first position on index 0, second on index 1, and so on... for example, if you have an array with 1000 items, the valid indexes are from 0 to 999.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17074/discussion-between-zvzej-and-luis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution as suggested by Luis was:

```
public void addCuestionarioToDb(){
  for (webResultCuestionario currentItem: CuestionarioArray){
    int cis = Integer.parseInt(currentItem._id)-1;   // just added the -1 here and runs perfect
    db.insertCuestionario(CuestionarioArray.get(cis).pregunta,  CuestionarioArray.get(cis).respuesta);
  }
}
```